# Mongo Query taking two backslash(\\) in where clause while setting single backslash(\)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, backslash

I am having a CSV file containg multiple rows. I am reading the CSV file and setting the where clause of my mongo query after reading each row.

This is how the row looks like.

```
WILLIAM PENN\145,12711061,WILLIAM PENN
```

As you see, The first column is containing only single backslash() but when I set the same in my mongo Query and do Sys.Out.print it shows two backslashes(\) like this

```
BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
                List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
                obj.add(new BasicDBObject("merchantId", storesArray[0]));
                obj.add(new BasicDBObject("terminalId", storesArray[1]));
                obj.add(new BasicDBObject("terminalOwnerName", storesArray[2]));
                andQuery.put("$and", obj);
```

> { "$and" : [ { "merchantId" : "WILLIAM PENN\\145"} , { "terminalId" : "12711061"} , { "terminalOwnerName" : "WILLIAM PENN"}]}

How can I remove that extra backslash from it ?

Comment: try this  ---> obj=obj.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\");